# uitableview not reload again in half view like facebook Half view

Tags: uitableview, jasidepanels

I have made an application, in which I have used uitableview in Half view like facebook, when I go to half view using swipe, then uitableview does not reload, but it reloads when I run it first time,So if anyone knows about it, please tell me.
Thanks

Comment: plz put some code in your app.

Answer (score 0):

I have subclassed JASidePanel and in that subclass I override a method as show below:

```
- (void)toggleLeftPanel:(id)sender
{
    [((MyLeftPanelViewController *)self.leftPanel) myReloadMethodInMyLeftPanelViewController];
    [super toggleLeftPanel:sender];
}
```

This works when using the left navigation button to navigate to the left panel, but I think a similar approach would work for swipe. I figured this out by looking in the header file for JASidePanel and then tracing the code.